# Блок if-сравнений в php

Tags: php, if

Можно ли вместо этого -

```
if( ($type == 'smth1') || ($type == 'smth2') ) {}
```

Написать так -

```
if( $type == ('smth1' || 'smth2')) {}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нет, выражение в скобках ожидаемо приведется к bool

Comment: Спасибо. А есть какие-нибудь пути упрощения конструкции?
Можно использовать switch/case, но получается более громоздко.

Comment: @Req только `in_array()` с большим количеством вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Условия приводятся к булеву типу. Скобки заставляют сначала выбрать одну строку. Приведение строки `smth1` вернёт ожидаемое `true`, второе даже высчитываться не будет. Значение переменной `$type` проверят с вернувшейся строкой. Т.е. всегда будет проверятся первое значение (если, конечно, оно при приведении не даёт `false`). Без вариантов.

Решение может быть типа такого:

```
<?
$type = 'smth1';
$opts = ['smth1', 'smth2']; // Варианты значений
if(preg_match("!^(" . implode('||', $opts) . ")$!", $type))
    print 'Found!';
else
    print '[404]';
```